# Upload file from URL to FTP using cURL

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, ftp

I need to upload a file to my FTP server using cURL. let me explain better.

I have this URL http://www.server.com/file.zip and I need to copy the "file.zip" to a FTP server without having to download it to my PC.

I have seen some examples that use cURL to upload files but are they are my hard drive and I need is upload from a URL.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know if you're saving it properly, just use the stream.

```
<?php

// open some file for reading
$file = 'http://server.com/file.zip';
$fp = fopen($file, 'r');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to upload $file
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $file, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

By the way, I'm just using PHP Manual examples for these answers. You should, too. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fput.php).

Comment: I get this error "There was a problem while uploading Resource id #3"

Comment: You either have an `FTP` problem, or the file wasn't actually downloaded to the server because of permissions. Used `chmod` to fix the latter.

Comment: I check the information of the FTP and change the permissions to 777, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Check to see if the file was downloaded, first

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not know how to check if the file was downloaded. thanks for the help, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Are you on a UNIX host that you have shell access to?

Comment: I'm running the script on a free hosting, my only access is via FTP or HTTP

Comment: Now  the script run delayed and in the FTP server saw a temporary file, but when the scrip ended the file disappeared.

Comment: The code works, but when I try to upload a large file, says he did successfully and  see in the FTP server while temporary file is uploading, but eventually disappears.

Answer (score -1):

i know its abit late but for anyone who needs this i spent hours looking for something similar
http://bgallz.org/1345/php-upload-multiple-files-url/